# Automation: how to automate transforming .doc to .docx?

Tags: automation

I have a bunch of .doc files in a folder which I need to convert to .docx.

To manually convert the .doc to .docx is pretty simple:

1. Open .doc in Word 2007
2. Click on Save As...
3. Save it as .docx

However, doing this for hundreds of files definitely ain't fun. =p

How would you automate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automate Word.

If you are using .NET, add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (make sure it is version 12 - equivalent to Word 2007 so you can achieve the above) reference assembly to your project and use it it automate word app to do exactly what you want to do above. The pseudocode

- Create the application object
- Use the application object to open a document (by supplying it the file name)
- Use the application object to perform SaveAs by supplying to it the format and output filename
- Close the current document
- Loop through the above till you finish with all documents
- Housekeeping code to release the Word or Doc objects

You can find plenty of example on google, just search for Word Automation in C# or something along that line.

Comment: Saving it as the new file format does not convert the file to that format. When you do it the way you detailed and open the new file it will sometimes open in compatibility mode since you only changed the extension. You need to call the Convert() method on the document object to truly convert to the newest file format.

Answer (score 25):

There is no need to automate Word, which is rather slow and brittle due to pop-up messages, or to use Microsoft's Office File Converter (ofc.exe), which has an unnecessarily complicated user interface.

The simplest and fastest way would be to install either Office 2007 or download and install the Compatibility Pack from Microsoft (if not already done). Then you can convert from .doc to .docx easily using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\wordconv.exe" -oice -nme <input file> <output file>
```

where <input file> and <output file> need to be fully qualified path names.

The command can be easily applied to multiple documents using `for`:

```
for %F in (*.doc) do "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\wordconv.exe" -oice -nme "%F" "%Fx"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Comment: Any solution for MacOS?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use the command-line **[Office File Converter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179019.aspx)**. Just run

```
ofc
```

and the magic happens.

Comment: Just FYI for readers: OFC is not supported now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on macOS or Windows, it's as easy as installing the Python package `doc2docx` and running the following commands:

`pip install doc2docx`

`find "/path/to/doc/directory" -type f -name "*.doc" -exec doc2docx {} \;`

Comment: this is a very handy suggestion. Any thoughts on how to get around the fact macOS requires Word to be granted file access for each file in the batch?

Comment: It's hacky, but if you relocate all of your `.doc` files to `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents` before running the whole batch through `doc2docx` all at once, you can bypass the macOS file access issue entirely. Unfortunately, I don't believe there exists a better way to accomplish this. If you're doing things programmatically, you can get away with using that directory only temporarily and exclusively for the conversion like I do here: https://github.com/cosmojg/confluence-markdown-exporter/blob/main/confluence-markdown-export.py#L82C1-L83C1

Answer (score 2):

Install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/).

Use the command line tool:

```
soffice --convert-to docx *.doc
```