# Creating .docx files from RTF templates

Tags: docx, bi-publisher

I using BI publisher desktop API to create doc from RTF templates. I want to use templates so that any slight modifications in presentation can be made directly in templates. Currently I am able to create only doc file because creating docx is not supported in BIP. Is there any way in which i can create docx using rtf templates or maybe convert doc to docx (a workaround I am ready for)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what "I using BI publisher desktop API to create doc from RTF templates." means. Assuming that you're invoking [BI Publisher Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22259/javaapis.htm) to generate reports. Currently .docx format is not supported by BI Publisher, but Word can help you convert .doc to .docx. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405417/automation-how-to-automate-transforming-doc-to-docx) for detail. So basically you need to create a command string and call it with [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method.